# How to speed up writing to an Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am currently using Interop objects to write to an Excel spreadsheet. Using stopwatches, I have found that the following implementation is quite timely. The processes in the `foreach` loop will usually take around 50 seconds to write around 2000 rows, each with 9 columns.

Is there any way to speed this up?

```
List<string[]> allEntries = fillStringArrayList();

// Set-up for running Excel
xls = new Excel.Application();
workBooks = xls.Workbooks;
workBook = workBooks.Open(workbookPath);
var workSheet = workBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];

// Insert new entries
foreach (string[] entry in allEntries)
{
    // Get the final row in the sheet that is being used
    Excel.Range usedRange = workSheet.UsedRange;
    int rowCount = usedRange.Rows.Count;

    // Format Column A to be type "text"
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1].NumberFormat = "@";

    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1] = entry[0];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 2] = entry[1];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 3] = entry[2];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 4] = entry[3];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 5] = entry[4];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 6] = entry[5];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 7] = entry[6];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 8] = entry[7];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 9] = entry[8];
}
```

Comment: Check CopyFromRecordset. Notes https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246335

Comment: `Using stopwatches` => and release mode with optimization enabled?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Yes & yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to assign the array to a range, instead of break and assign cell by cell:

```
Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1];
Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 9];
Excel.Range range = workSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
range.Value = entry;
```

Edit:
If you want to speed up things even more, you could assign a bidimensional array (string[,], where the first dimension is the lines and the second the columns) to a range of the same size.

```
int firstLine = rowCount + 1;
Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[firstLine, 1];

//Gets the size of the first dimension of the array
int arrayXSize = allEntries.GetLength(0); 

Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[firstLine + arrayXSize -1, 9];
Excel.Range range = workSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);

//allEntries is a string[,]
range.Value = allEntries;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is 50% faster.

Comment: @Queue You could speed things even more if you can modify fillStringArrayList() to return a string[,] instead of List<string[]>. Then you could assign the entire allEntries to a single range of the same size.

Comment: Magnificent! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show this implementation?

Comment: @Queue Added. Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent. Only takes a fraction of a second now.